# How to use ionic ui inside existing cordova project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

In the cordova documentation it is mentioned that we can use ui frameworks such as ionic and react inside our cordova project. But they have not mentioned steps or instructions for the same. I want to use ionic components inside my existing cordova project.
I am a beginner in cordova and have no clue how this can be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to follow these steps in the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cdn

Comment: I think this doesn't  work for mobile apps.

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to say. What doesnt work for mobile apps?

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned in the link. And tried to implement  some buttons but all of them were plain white buttons. The styling wasn't  there.

Comment: sounds like your missing the styles tags. if you follow the link i sent, it will show you where to add those.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your reply. I have created an ionic/angular project with cordova. Will be working on it. Can you tell if its possible to create custom cordova plugins for such a project? And if I want to make changes to the platform code such as mainactivity , manifest file etc do i have to follow a separate method or I can make changes directly?